# Problem with Samba Shares on Fedora Server 32, Can see shared folder but cannot open it on Linux and Windows Clients

Tags: fedora

I'm setting up a new Fedora Server to act as a file host for my home network. I have install and configured Samba and it is running.

The problem I'm running into is i can see the server on network browse from both a Windows and Linux system, and i can see the folder that is being shared, however when i try to open the folder Windows gives error 0x80070043, and the linux system says "Unable to access location, Failed to mount Windows Share: invalid argument"

This is my smb.conf

[global]

```
    server role = standalone server
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    map to guest = Bad User
    usershare allow guests = yes
    hosts allow = 192.168.0.0/16
    hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0
```

[Network Data]

```
    comment = Network Data
    path = /NetworkData2/NetworkData
    read only = no
    guest ok = yes
    force user = jharrell
    force group = jharrell
```

The other thing is with this server i have a 250GB boot dirve that Fedora Server sits on and a 2TB HDD for the data storage. The 2TB is mounted at /NetworkData2 and i can confirm that the folder NetworkData is the only folder on the 2TB drive.

Any idea what could be going on ?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text, instead post the file as text into the question. Screenshots of text have accessibility issues, and also make it harder for people to quote them etc.

Comment: Is SELinux turned on? Does the user jharrell have access to the folder?

Comment: Yes, jharrell does have access to the folder

Comment: And is SELinux on?

Comment: Yes, the server is Enforcing SELinux

Comment: How are you connecting? Try troubleshooting with smbclient or "net use": https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch12.html#INDEX-56

Comment: On the Windows in file explore \\Server_IP and on the linux machines smb:\\Server_IP  Runing the smbclient tool i get this,  protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_NETWORK_RESPONSE

Answer (score 0):

So here is how this got fixed

After using the troubleshooting guild, i was reading up on SELinux when google searching that they were using another hard drive. If you do not share a folder that is on the same Hard Drive that the OS is installed on you have to do things differently, in my case i have a 2TB HDD that is the data storage for this server and what i wanted to share via Samba

Over on serverfault i found this post that helped me in the right direction

https://serverfault.com/questions/395486/i-can-connect-to-samba-server-but-cannot-access-shares

I learned that i had to change the permission at the mount point, in my case /NetworkData2 and add that to SELinux.

After i completed  that i could access the folder in Windows Files Explorer and my Linux machine files, however another problem popped up where i did not have permission to write to the folder. It turns out that root had control over the folder and would not let any writing go on in the folder. so i changed the permissions on the /NetworkData2 folder and not i can read and write to and from it and the shares are working.